# Interactive Chart - DevExpress - Point Series

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, charts, devexpress

Hi I have existin chart where it Point View.

On X axis it is time horizon e.g. 3 Months, 6 Months, 1 year, 2 year, 5 year, 10 year, 20, 30 year.

On y Axis there is %

Each X and Y intersaction point is shown as Point...

Now I want to make this chart interactive. What I want to achieve is to user to give flexibility to move individual points on Y axis so that user can create their custm curve. And once user is satisfied with the curve they should be able to save it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the answer in this thread provides a sufficient information to achieve what you want: 
[Can we Drag and drop point in point chart or bar in bar chart update corresponding data grid control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q262662.aspx)